# Confusion regarding transitive set $X$ and the relation $\in$ on $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So, let me expand on the title.

Suppose a set $X$ is transitive, is it then true that $\in$ is a transitive relation on $X$?

I'm just slightly confused by what the question is.

Assuming $X$ is transitive, then $(a\in b\wedge b\in X) \implies a\in X$. But, is the question above asking if for $a,b,c \in X$ we have $(a\in b \wedge b\in c \implies a\in c)$? This just means that $c$ is itself transitive, and clearly this is false since not all elements of a transitive set is transitive itself.

The other interpretation, meaning $c=X$, seems a bit easy since it's literally the definition.

I know it can be difficult to deduce the author's meaning of a question, but I'm hoping some of you experienced folk know the intention of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first interpretation is the correct one.  The question is asking whether $\in$, considered as a binary relation on the set $X$, is a transitive relation.  You are correct that the answer is no because an element of a transitive set need not be transitive (though for completeness you should perhaps give an explicit example of this).

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. As to the example, this would do right? Let $X = \{\{\emptyset\}\}$, which is not transitive, and let $Y=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, X\}$. If $a\in b \in Y$, then either $b=\{\emptyset\}$ or $b=X$, thus $a=\emptyset$ or $a=\{\emptyset\}$, both in $Y$.

Comment: Yep, that's the simplest example I think.

Comment: Fantastic. Time to type it up. Thank you.

Comment: What about the converse? Then $(a\in b \wedge b\in c)\Rightarrow a\in c$ only for elements $a,b,c \in X$. But for $X$ to be a transitive set, $(a\in b \wedge b\in X) \Rightarrow a\in X$, which is essentially swapping out $c$ for $X$, violating the ZF-axioms. No?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "violating the ZF-axioms", but the converse is indeed false in general.  Try to find a counterexample!

Comment: Sorry, I was being lazy and didn't want to look up the axiom. What I meant was if $c=X$ then $X\in X$ which violates the axiom of Foundation? But as you say, a counterexample may be the best way to show it.

Comment: A counterexample is the _only_ way to show it.  The fact that $X\not\in X$ just means that one possible means of proving the converse doesn't work.  It doesn't mean the converse isn't true.

Comment: Right, of course. Anyway, I have a counterexample now. Thank you for all the help. Case closed.